# Feasibility of obtaining a 210µF 4.5kV DC capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, supercapacitor

I'm looking for a high-capacitance, high-voltage capacitor for a experiment I'm interested in trying out (i.e. order of 100µF rated for at least 4.5kV DC). I realise these specifications may be unrealistic, and am yet to find any capacitors like this available online.

My question is: is this sort of capacitor even remotely possible to obtain? And if not, are there any substitutes that have similar properties (e.g. capacitor banks)?

Comment: 4.5kV DC or AC? If AC, what's the frequency range?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Apologies, 4.5kV DC.

Comment: does it have to be one capacitor or can you accept an equivalent series / parallel combination?

Comment: @vicatcu equivalents are perfectly fine, as long as it doesn't involve something stupid like 500 0.4uF capacitors in parallel.

Comment: Microwave oven capacitors are rated for over 2 kV, so you'd only need two in series to make the voltage. They tend to have 10 M bleeder resistors in them as well, so they ought to balance nicely. Now you just have to find a friendly junk-yard operator who will 'lend' you old microwaves as they come in, that you return less the caps, to get the number of parallel strings required. It need only cost you a few beers, but it will cost a lot of time and space.

Comment: @Neil_UK that advice should come with a big 'do not try this at home' warning... taking apart microwaves is no joke.

Comment: @jumbot I'm not sure that charging a 100 uF cap to 4.5 kV (1 kJ) is particularly risible either. I've lost count of the number I've taken apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is this sort of capacitor even remotely possible to obtain? And if not, are there any substitutes that have similar properties (e.g. capacitor banks)?

There are capacitor banks but not for DC. Those are designed to operate across very high line voltages, and capacitances are not high.

I don't know if there are commercial products for your purpose but what you can do is to connect 10 of [1000μ / 450V](https://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/capacitors/aluminium-electrolytic-capacitors?capacitance=1000uf&voltage-rating=450v) (or, with a 10% margin, [1000μ / 500V](https://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/capacitors?capacitance=1000uf&voltage-rating=500v)) capacitors in series to get 100μF / 4.5kV capacitor.

This is practically achievable, but quite expensive and large. I'm not sure but can be a bit heavy as well. But it may be even fun to build such a bank.

Remember to put equal resistances (a bit higher like 470k or 1M) across each capacitor so that each capacitor share equal voltage.

Comment: Wow, that is rather expensive... maybe I'll leave this one for a rainy day. But good answer, thank you.

Comment: If lower leakage is desired (i.e. because the high voltage supply doesn't put out much current), film capacitors like Panasonic's EZP-E80506MTA might be better suited. I've used them in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly possible. It would likely be one or more oil-filled capacitors for that voltage.

For example, I see 16uF/7.5kV (sort-of on the voltage rating) caps on eBay. 13 of those in parallel would do it, though not optimal. They’re big, heavy and expensive - several thousand dollars for the lot, and each is ~8” (200mm) tall.

Comment: With eBay finds like that, keep in mind that many old oil-filled capacitors are very, very toxic. (chlorinated diphenyls)

Comment: @JonathanS. yes, that’s worth mentioning. This one contains no polychlorinated biphenyls (PCBs) but old ones may. They are not particularly nasty unless they burn, in which case they are quite bad (dioxins can be created). Happens my better half, as a chemist, was involved in creating the regulatory regime for PCBs so I have some secondary knowledge on the matter.